# How to offset an item in a layer list

Tags: android

I have this layer list file in my drawables. I'm wondering how to offset the icon overlayed over the shape item. I currently have the gravity set to center, but is there a way to offset from the center?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- background shape -->
    <item>
        <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>
        <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#ffffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- 
    icon that overlays the background shape; this icon
    has gravity set to center, but how can I change offset
    from center?
    -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_on_angled"
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <padding android:left="100dp"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:top`, `android:bottom`, `android:right`, or `android:left`.

Offest 2dp from right and centered:

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/action_bar_icon"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <padding android:left="100dp"/>
</item>
```

[image]